# Twitter bootstrap hamburger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my practice web page to show a hamburger menu when on a mobile device, but no matter what I try nothing seems to get it to go that hamburger menu. I have tried to copy the code exactly how it looks on the bootstrap website, but again it's not working. I feel like I may be missing a plug in or using the wrong bootstrap file, the full length of code is detailed below.

**Other Contextual Information**

I am currently learning how to code through an online course and I have come to the section on twitter bootstrap. It seems the professor is teaching an older version of bootstrap; since none of what he is saying is directly lining up with the bootstrap website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>


<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

 <style>

 .box {

 background-color:#d3d3d3;

 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="navbar">

    <div class="navbar-inner">

        <div class="container">


          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>



          <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>


          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">scout</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">chill</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">chill</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>

   </div>

</div>        

 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

 <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="span6 box">Content</div>

        <div class="span6 box">Content</div>

    </div>

 </div>


 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should add a working [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the template posted on getbootstrap.com.  View full page and zoom in to see the burger menu.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <!-- burger icon -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello world</a>
    </div>



    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>



      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I believe that `.nav.nav-tabs` are used for "in-page" [navigation tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_comp_nav-tabs&stacked=h).  I've never seen it used in a navbar but I may be wrong.  And if your professor is using `bootstrap 2`, the documentation is located [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar) for your reference.  A good way to learn bootstrap is go to the [bootstrap components page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/), right-click on any element you want to learn about and click on `inspect element` to see the html of the component.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thanks! I will take a look at the boot strap 2 documentation as well.